# stimulsoft-HTML style(for example font and font-size) not apply

Tags: stimulsoft

good timing...
I have a text that I have set for that styles. For example, set two different font for sections.
In stimulsoft, I put a text field and AllowHtmlTags set true.
The problem I have is that fonts are not applied to the html and pdf export
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can not use all tag `HTML` in this app, 
And that all tag `HTML` app can support for you
[Link all Tag HTML support in stimulsoft](https://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=40222)